# How to make custom regex for include leading zero?

Tags: javascript, regex

I created a customed regex it works fine with any dynamic numbers. But it does not include/accept leading zeros.

Here is my regex:

```
Dial(0|[1-9][0-9]*)_(0|[1-9][0-9]*)
```

When I test in regexr, I observed it does not accept the next of leading zero part *(not highlighted)*
[image]

---

It should accept *"Dial733_001"*, *"Dial26_0000005"*, *"Dial6_00100"*

It should not accept *"Dial6s_001"*, *"Dials6_001"*, *"Dial1_s001"*, *"Dial1_001s"*

Comment: Did you mean to exclude zeros from captures? `Dial0*([1-9][0-9]*)_0*([1-9][0-9]*)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I mean it should accept/capture leading zero. your answer is correct partially but it accepts strings at last like *"Dial552_99944ssss"*

Comment: Then add a word boundary, `Dial0*([1-9][0-9]*)_0*([1-9][0-9]*)\b`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks sir it help. Will you post it as answer so I will accept. or I will just closed the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
\bDial0*([1-9][0-9]*)_0*([1-9][0-9]*)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H2O4tX/1/). *Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `Dial`  - a word `Dial`
- `0*` - zero or more `0` chars
- `([1-9][0-9]*)` - Group 1: a non-zero digit and then zero or more digits
- `_` - an underscore
- `0*` - zero or more `0` chars
- `([1-9][0-9]*)` - Group 2: a non-zero digit and then zero or more digits
- `\b` - word boundary